# How to build a double X table leg

Tags: furniture

I'm looking to build some table legs with a double X design.

[image]

The top is about 40" wide (round) and weighs 120lbs. I should think that 4x4 posts should do it, but maybe they need to be bigger? I can find many how-to documents about building a single X design by notching half of each post, but the double X seems more complicated if I want it to support the weight of the top and everything placed on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, although it is a little bit difficult to show in a simple sketch.  Sorry, but the cross section sketches show the joints horizontally instead of in vertical orientation. Give me some feedback if this is not clear enough.:

The legs do not have to be 4" to support the weight, but they may be needed to get the 4-way intersection to work.

Two legs in one plane act as the primary assembly and are lap-joined with a notch in each leg to allow them to cross each other.
[image: Primary legs cross]

Next the opposite legs do not cross through. Instead create a 90 degree joint with a spline (dashed line) centered in each leg to support the 90 degree bend. (Shown in red).  These legs will set in a mortise cut (not shown & narrower than the full leg width) into the sides of the primary legs (black lines).

[image: Secondary legs.]

A section through the combined legs is shown below.
[image: Cross section]

The primary and secondary legs can be joined in a glued joint provided the boards are in good contact with each other.  Otherwise consider some through dowels to reinforce the joints.  I strongly suggest that you make a test model before attempting this for the actual project.  There are bound to be complications that you did not consider that can be worked out in a test.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would probably start by making 4 half-X's that are half-lapped. Then miter them all together. The glued half lapped half-x's oriented vertically will support the weight of the top, and they can be mitered together, and even doweled or connected using a floating tenon at that point as well.

[image: Half-X]

[image: Top View]

[image: Iso]

Answer (score -2):

You could do something like this:

[image]

http://www.themag.it/inspiration/2011/join-table.html

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  We try to avoid links to external sites, so I inserted your photo.  However, on its own, the photo is of limited help without some sort of schematic to explain the actual component construction.

Comment: It's based on an something called the devil's knot that I think came from a japanese burr type puzzle.  The reason for the link was so that other photos of this could be seen, especially the one with the separate pieces.  Figured someone could scale the pictures up to get dimensions.